# Archiving in Xcode 6 does not use provisioning profile if device plugged in

Tags: xcode

I was doing an archive in Xcode 6 with my development iPad and iPhone plugged in. The archive that was created would only install on the device that was selected for the scheme, regardless of what provisioning profile was selected. When I unplugged all of my testing devices and archived the devices in the provisioning profile were used.

This seems to be different behaviour from previous. I have built many archives over the years with test devices plugged in.

Has anyone else run into this?